# SQL order by numeric and string attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

The problem im having is relating an order by query which contains numeric and datetime values and will sort ASC and also having a string value which needs sorting in a specific order high to low.  Im able to sort the priority itself in a query using case, but not able to add in any other conditions for the other values.  Another problem is that the selection of which order they are ordered in is decided during run time so the order will change.

Sorts Priority alone

```
SELECT [Task], [Start Date] AS Start_Date, [End Date] AS End_Date, [Priority], [Time Allowance] AS Time_Allowance, [Details] FROM [schedulerData0]
ORDER BY (CASE Priority
 WHEN 'Very High' Then 1  
 WHEN 'High' Then 2 
 WHEN 'Medium' Then 3 
 WHEN 'Low' Then 4 
 WHEN 'Very Low' Then 5
END)
```

Attempt at combining cases

```
SELECT [Task], [Start Date] AS Start_Date, [End Date] AS End_Date, [Priority], [Time Allowance] AS Time_Allowance, [Details] FROM [schedulerData0]
ORDER BY
-- numeric columns
CASE _orderby WHEN 'Time_Allowance' THEN Time_Allowance END ASC;
-- string columns
CASE _orderby Priority
 WHEN Priority = 'Very High' THEN 1,
 WHEN Priority = 'High' THEN 2,
 WHEN Priority = 'Medium' THEN 3,
 WHEN Priority = 'Low' THEN 4,
 WHEN Priority = 'Very Low' THEN 5;
-- datetime columns
CASE _orderby WHEN 'Start_Date' THEN Start_Date END ASC,
CASE _orderby WHEN 'End_Date' THEN End_Date END DESC;
END
```

currently have statement below with the attribute stated by first second and third selection.  As this will sort all numeric data but alphabetically sort priority.

```
SELECT [Task], [Start Date] AS Start_Date, [End Date] AS End_Date, [Priority], [Time Allowance] AS Time_Allowance, [Details] FROM [schedulerData0] ORDER BY [" + firstSelect + "], [" + secondSelect + "], [" + thirdSelect + "]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT [Task], [Start Date] AS Start_Date, [End Date] AS End_Date, [Priority], [Time     Allowance] AS Time_Allowance, [Details] FROM [schedulerData0]
ORDER BY (CASE Priority
  WHEN 'Very High' Then 1  
  WHEN 'High' Then 2 
  WHEN 'Medium' Then 3 
  WHEN 'Low' Then 4 
  WHEN 'Very Low' Then 5
END), [Start Date] ASC, [End Date] DESC
```

Comment: Once the END has been hit anything after brings up an incorrect syntax error

Comment: @jamesmews Updated, missed a ")" after the END and remove the last one